# TFS: wrong build order

Tags: tfs, build-process

I have a solution file which is built on TFS.
I added project dependences and the project is built well locally but the build order on the TFS is not correct, so I have an error while building.
What can be the problem? (TFS 2010, Solution - too)

*i've read something about such issues with Any CPU configuration. Maybe here is my problem*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons projects in the solution were built in the order that they are listed in .sln file (with dependences).

Comment: Just had this issue. Man, that is horrible. I logged this bug on Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1988516

Answer (score 0):

Locally you can have the correct dll's in de bin folder so you solution will build local but on the server it won't.

You can set up the correct build order when you go to the Project menu, choose Project Dependencies. Here can you set the dependencies of all projects in you solution. When this is all set up correctly Visual Studio sets the correct Build Order.

You can check the Build Order in the second tab of that window. When the Build Order is not correct you probably not have set the right dependencies.

Comment: Of course I checked the build order (maybe I wrote it insufficiently clear in my question). On my local machine that order is correct.

Comment: Ok, what error do you get? Can you edit your question with that error so we can see that?

Comment: I had an error which is referred to my solution build process. It's not the Visual studio or TFS error. One project (database) wasn't built, so another one could not take scripts and copy them and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I had a *similar* issue with TFS2012. In my case, I had all of the project dependencies set correctly but the build started with a project somewhere in the middle and thus the build failed. I didn't have an opportunity to see which project it was going to try to build next.

In my case, I took over the project and the Configuration Manager settings for the projects were completely messed. When I tried to create a Debug | x86 build, almost none of the projects were set to compile if x86 was selected. I had to update the settings in Configuration Manager for all of the platforms I needed and the build worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

After manually edit the project order in the solution file, the teambuild works like a charm. So maybe you have to manually reorder the projects in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me it were rather missing

```
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {x} = {x}
    EndProjectSection
```

Attributes in the `Project.sln` than a wrong order of the entries.